# saving a text file into a linked list line by line in c

Tags: c, linked-list, file-handling

I need to save a text file into a linked list line by line and then display the saved elements.
Here is what I have tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct node 
{
    char data;
    struct node *next;
}Element, *List;

List init(void);

int main (){

    List current, head, newnode;
    FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    head = current = NULL;

    while (getc(f) != EOF){
        newnode = malloc(sizeof(Element));
        fgets(&newnode -> data, sizeof(newnode), f);
        newnode -> next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
            head = current = newnode;
        }
        else{
            current -> next = newnode;
            current = newnode;
        }

    }

    current = head;

    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%s", &current -> data);
        current = current -> next;
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

And the text is:

```
I stand amid the roar
Of a surf-tormented shore
And I hold within my hand
Grains of the golden sand
How few! yet how they creep
Through my fingers to the deep
While I weep while I weep
O God can I not grasp
Them with a tighter clasp
O God can I not save
One from the pitiless wave
Is all that we see or seem
But a dream within a dream
```

But what I get so far is:

```
 stnd midtheroa
f asur-tomened hor
nd  hod wthi myhan
rais o th godensan
ow ew!yethowthe crep
hrogh y fnges t th dep
hil I eepwhie Iwee
 Go ca I ot ras
hemwit a igher las
 Go ca I ot aveOnefro th piiles wve
s al tat e se o sem
ut  dram ithn adrem
```

it skips some characters and I think the reason is that fgets reads a definite amount of characters each time. But I can not find a solution to make it how it should be, and I'm not very good with the linked list concept yet.
I'd be very thankful for any help and advices to make it work and save Mr. Poe from this nonsense. 
PS: It should be done by using C90 so some functions are disabled.

Comment: `while (getc(f) != EOF){` consumes one character from the input stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A note from the comments: `getc` reads one character from the input stream. You need to check if the input stream is at the end of the file some other way.

You're using a single `char` instead of an array of `char`s. Use `char data[51];`, `fgets(newnode->data, sizeof(newnode->data), f);`, and `printf("%s", current->data);`

Comment: `feof()` is a bad advice. Even as `do{...} while(!feof(fp));`